# How to get indirect access on a file through script in linux

Tags: permissions, sed

I have one file text1, on this only one user(user1) has read,write,execute permissions, rest of the world(user2) has read and execute permissions. I thought of having one script which changes the contents of the file text1 as below which will be executed by user2

```
sed -i '/s/eg1/eg0/' text1
```

I want to modify the above script to change the contents of text1 with out directly giving write access to user2. I mean to say user2 shouldn't able to directly write to text1 but when he executes the script the contents of text1 should be modified as it is not possible to give direct write access on text1

Comment: So you want to write to it without the write permission? Can you it as root/modify the permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this procedure:

- login as user1
- save your command in script file, for example `changeText.sh`
- make it executable:

  ```
    chmod 755 changeText.sh
  ```
- set SUID (Set owner User ID up on execution) permission:

  ```
    chmod u+s changeText.sh
  ```

After this, `changeTest.sh` looks like:

```
      -rwsr-xr-x 1 user1 user1 xxxx nov 15  2014 /path/to/file/changeText.sh
```

SUID gives temporary permissions to a user to run a program/file with the permissions of the file owner rather that the user who runs it.

In other word, when `user2` runs `/path/to/file/changeText.sh` will get file owner’s permissions and will change text in file text1, even if `user2` has not write permission.

[Here](http://www.linuxnix.com/2011/12/suid-set-suid-linuxunix.html) is a useful link.